# Python Pandas how to multiply by the previous value of a string when calculating in another formula

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Csv file with a calculation that looks something like this:

| Average Value |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 9 |
| 20 |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

I want to make a calculation in a new column using the formula "Y = (2/(N+1))*X+(1-(2/(N+1)))*Y1 "

Where N is the period that is given when calling the class. Here N will be 10

X = Average Value

Y1 = previous calculation of Y

I was doing something like

```
df['Y'] = ((2//(N + 1))*df.Average Value + (1-(2//(N + 1)))).cumsum().fillna(0)
```

But it doesn't work

Desired result

| Average Value | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.18 |
| 5 | 1.84 |
| 9 | 3.14 |
| 20 | 6.20 |
| 3 | 5.61 |
| 2 | 4.95 |
| 4 | 4.77 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba) solution - is possible count by previous values:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, N):
    x = (2/(N + 1))
    y = 1-(2/(N + 1))
    d = np.empty(a.shape)
    d[0] = a[0] * x + y
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        d[i] = a[i] * x + d[i-1] * y 
    return d

df['Y'] = f(df['Average Value'].to_numpy(), 10)
```